# Using MSMQ to Store Data before Processing

Tags: vb.net, url, msmq

I am new to the formum and new to MSMQ.

I have been asked to do research on it, to see if it will help out business, but still not sure if and how it works. Here is a short Summary.

We have a service provider that will receive messages via a mobile phone, to which they will pass certain info(Such as the cell number, text in message, etc.) to a URL that we have given them, which is an app we created, which will then process the data and store into our Database etc etc.

However, as we at times receive between a few hundred to a few thousand at any given time(Spread out or at once) - We get timeouts.

What I would like to know, is it possible to get this info stored into a que using MSMQ, before it hits our URL(That we provided to our service provider), so that we can avoid timeouts ?

I hope this makes sense and that someone can help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSMQ is a transport protocol. It is designed to get data from A to B as fast and as reliably as possible. As it uses store-and-forward, it can be used as a data buffer at the sender. In your case, though, that's not important. I would recommend:

1. ISP sends MSMQ message over HTTP(S) to your server.
2. Message is stored on server's local queue.
3. Your app reads messages from queue.
4. Your app writes to database.
5. Goto 3

So you would be buffering the messages AFTER they reach your server.

The messages would also be buffered at the ISP in case of network outage between them and you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have been thinking about this a bit, and I think the problem comes from IIS and the timeout happens there at times, is there a way we can pass the information from the URL we provided to our ISP straight to a Queue, before it hits IIS ?

Comment: MSMQ over HTTP(S) is there to provide a secure way of exposing your MSMQ server to the Internet - i.e. you put a webserver in front. Exposing your MSMQ server directly is technically possible but not necessarily a good idea. You could open up the ports on your Internet firewall to allow native MSMQ traffic to flow.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Apologies for the late reply, I did not get a notification for your reply. However, this has unfortunately been put on hold, so I have not been able to continue doing research and testing. Thank you, nevertheless.